# How can I change the Google account used by the Google Lens app?

Tags: google-account

I use a Pixel 6 and Android 12. When opening the Google Lens app for the first time, the following dialog appears:

[image]

> **Welcome to Google Lens**
>
> Google Lens helps you search what you see. You're signed as `account@example.com`
> This account will be able to see your Lens, Search, and Assistant activity.
>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Continue</kbd>

How can I change the Google account used by the Google Lens app?

Comment: Try [changing Google app account](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/103186557/google-lens-via-google-photos-where-to-change-the-google-lens-account?hl=en) // I didn't try

Answer (score 1):

Lens seems to be integrated with the Google Assistant. So you'll want to change the account that is selected to be used for the Assistant.

**Fast way (using Settings search)**

- Settings (app)
- Search at the top for "assistant"
- Pick the account here you would rather use

**Long way (going only through menus)**

- Settings (app)
- *Apps & notifications*
- *Assistant*
- *See all Assistant Settings*
- Pick the account here you would rather use

[image]